# Is Ukranian crisis one of its kind?

Tags: ukraine, crimea

Ukraine is currently going through a big political crisis.Crimea is on verge of separation.There are specific peculiarities of this situation, which I have noted ahead.

- A country takes over a part of other country without use of any weapon.
- The attacked country does not retaliate at all(in military view).
- The people from region attacked/overtaken support the attackers.
- US thinks twice(or maybe more) before imposing sanctions.

But is this situation one of its kind? At least the first three conditions considered?

Comment: Although the similarities are superficial, the prime example that would meet all your conditions is the [Anschluss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anschluss). That said, I think this is more of a history question than a politics one.

Comment: Are you asking for historical analogies of this case?

Comment: @user4035 somewhat yes.But I wasn't sure if this is political question or historical one.

Comment: @YannisRizos As the crisis is ongoing but the analogy would be historical,I was confused whether to ask the question on *politics beta* or on *history beta*.If it's appropriate on history, please migrate it.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure the local population _really_ supports that, but apart from that, good question.

Comment: @Lohoris - based on all the polls I read (they are in russian), locals do.

Comment: Wouldn't the Sudetenland be a more accurate analogy, as Russia is taking over a historically and ethnically-Russian *part* of Ukraine, rather than the whole country?

Comment: Three bullet points apply to occupation of Baltic countries by Soviet Union (actually the same aggressor) at the beginning of world war two, just the people didn't really support the attackers.

Comment: It's the first time since WWII when the principle of territorial integrity is manifestly broken. Invasion on Georgia in 2008 is almost identical scenario, only that Abhazia and Osetia are formally not incorporated into Russia. The weapons were used on Crimea, but the Ukrainian army was unable to make any substantial resistence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the situation is not one of kind. There are a few notable examples, and there would be likely many examples of locations that would ***really like*** for this to occur, but they do not have a regional superpower supporting them. The reason is that nationalism became a force in the early 20th century.

> [Nationalism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationalism#Ethnic_nationalism) is a belief, creed or political ideology that involves an individual identifying with, or becoming attached to, one's nation. Nationalism involves national identity, by contrast with the related construct of patriotism

There are different forms, but the important one here is called ethnic nationalism.

> Some nationalists exclude certain groups. Some nationalists, defining the national community in ethnic, linguistic, cultural, historic, or religious terms...

**Historical Examples**
The Nazis were nationalists that believed in radical ethnic purity. They annexed Austria and then the [Sudetenland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudetenland) of Czechoslovakia with the support of these ethnic German communities and without military arms, since the Allies were trying to use appeasement with Germany and convinced the Czech government not to fight. Eventually warfare broke out in Czechoslovakia.

Yugoslavia was created through acts of diplomacy alone. It's proponents wanted a nation for Slavic people, so after WWI, the Allied Powers created the nation from several small Slavic kingdoms. Since the Ottomans and the Austrian Hungarian Empire were no longer able to fight, there was no further military conflict until WWII.

Comment: Warfare broke out when Germany attacked Poland. The war only got to the Czechoslovak territory at the end of the war.